# Angular 2 HTTP метод запроса DELETE уходит как OPTIONS

Tags: ajax, http, angular2

Как отправить запрос методом DELETE?

Делаю запрос на удаленный сервер на удаление. Метод запроса должен быть DELETE.

```
delete(id: number) {
  return this.http.delete('http://example.com/api/3').catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Удаление не происходит, т.к. запрос уходит методом OPTIONS. Вот что пишет отладчик Chrome:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Кажется Angular перед каждым запросом отправляет `OPTIONS` запрос, чтобы убедится в том, что требуемый вам запрос поддерживается.

Comment: @AnatolySamokisha, не перед каждым

Comment: По ссылке больше информации. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Preflighted_requests

Comment: это сложный запрос называется, вот читай https://learn.javascript.ru/xhr-crossdomain